# Table.ExpandTableColumn first row only

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I want to use Power Query to extract a related table using `Table.ExpandTableColumn.`  Instead of expanding the entire related table I would like to expand only the first row.

In the attempt below, I am extracting the entire **"Name"** column.

```
= Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Changed Type", "ToRecipients", {"Name"}, {"ToRecipients.Name"})
```

Any ideas?

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How would it work wit this?

```
Table.ExpandTableColumn(

    // Retaining only first rows in the nested tables
    Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Name", each Table.FirstN(_, 1)}),

    "ToRecipients", {"Name"}, {"ToRecipients.Name"}
)
```

Alternatively,

```
Table.ExpandRecordColumn(

    // Retaining only first rows in the nested tables as 'records'
    Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Name", Table.First}),

    "ToRecipients", {"Name"}, {"ToRecipients.Name"}
)
```

Both works just the same. Later one may be looking simpler a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Guess it should have been like below;

```
= Table.ExpandTableColumn( Table.TransformColumns(
                      #"Changed Type", {"ToRecipients", each Table.FirstN(_, 1)}),

"ToRecipients", {"Name"}, {"ToRecipients.Name"})
```

...

```
Table.ExpandRecordColumn(

// Retaining only first rows in the nested tables as 'records'
Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {"ToRecipients", Table.First}),

"ToRecipients", {"Name"}, {"ToRecipients.Name"})
```